# How to manage Task Lifecycle

Tags: android

I am implementing a passcode feature, in which a passcode window will be prompted to user whenever any activity in the same task stack become visible(previously the whole task are in the background).

Because my activity structure is not flat, I wonder what is to best way to manage this kind of issue.

In short, how can I get notified when the task stack becomes visible?

Answer (score 0):

I am using a static member to monitor weither the activity in on front or background in my project and so far it is working! For example **public static boolean bIsFront;**
onStart activity is visible   **bIsFront = true** 
onPause activity is going to background **bIsFront = false**

Comment: This doesn't fix my issue. The problem is, onResume of an activity is always called after the onPause of another activity. Thus, I cannot detect if the activity is resumed upon task wake-up.

Comment: Try to set the flag bIsFront = true in onStart.In my app it is onStart, sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I end up doing the following to solve my problem:

1. take down the time when activity is paused and save that in preference
2. compare the last pause time with current time. If it's greater than 1 sec, it means the task has just woken up, otherwise, it's not.

It works, but I wonder if there is any better solution.

A caveat of this solution is if an activity from another application is launched into my task stack, I will treat it as not an activity in my task stack.